# problema ao configurar um repositorio GIT com bare

Tags: git

Eu tenho um repositório de um servidor que deu problema e não foi possível clonar os repositórios dele para o GIT do servidor novo, então eu copiei o ambiente de desenvolvimento da aplicação toda através do pendrive, está da seguinte forma. apos instalar o GIT sem problema.

dentro de `/var/git/projeto.git` estão os diretórios e arquivos do GIT e dentro de `/usr/share/www/html` está a aplicação. 
dentro do diretório `/var/git/projeto.git` eu copiei os diretórios do servidor antigo que pertencem ao GIT:

```
HEAD branches description hooks info objects refs config index logs packed-refs
```

então rodei o comando:

```
/var/git/projeto.git$ git init --shared --bare
Initialized shared Git repository in... /var/git/projeto.git
```

dentro de `/usr/share/www/html/` onde esta a aplicação usei o comando.

```
/usr/share/www/html/$ git add --all
```

Ele adicionou os arquivos para monitorar, porem quando altero alguma coisa remotamente e uso um `git commit` e depois `git pull`, etc., não aparece a alteração no arquivo

dentro de `/var/git/projeto.gt/hooks` eu alterei o *script* para jogar as alterações que subirem com o *pull* para o local correto `/usr/share/www/html/`

Eu já busquei vários artigos sobre mas nenhuma me esclareceu o por que está acontecendo isso.

Comment: Seu problema esta ainda atual? Se sim, você pode explicar de novo com mais de precisos por favor?

Comment: o remote do repositório clonado em `/var/share/www/html` está apontando para `/var/git/projeto.git` corretamente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verifique o apontamento para o remoto. O projeto ainda deve esta olhando par ao servidor antigo. `git remote -v`. Você então pode adicionar um novo remoto. `git remote add upstream /var/git/...` e executar os comandos *pull* *push* para ele. `git pull upstream master`. 
O nome `upstream` pode ser qualquer um.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote